# Get birthplace and date of American investors from DBpedia people in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm trying to get a list of Investors from the US, their birth dates, and places.
But the SPARQL code below doesn't seem to work. I tried it on both

DBpedia pages:
https://live.dbpedia.org/sparql or
https://dbpedia.org/snorql/

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

SELECT ?name ?birthPlace ?birthDate
WHERE {
  ?person a dbo:BusinessPerson, dbo:Entrepreneur, dbo:Investor .
  ?person dbo:birthPlace ?birthPlace .
  ?person dbo:birthDate ?birthDate .
  ?person dbo:country dbr:United_States .
  ?person rdfs:label ?name .
  FILTER(LANG(?name) = 'en')
}
```

Can't find any good literature on this subject either so having trouble understanding what I should alter.

All advice is appreciated.

Comment: so, the question you have to solve is, what makes a person an investor on Wikipedia resp. then DBpedia? The common way is to open example DBpedia pages in your browser to see what kind of data the have in common or might be appropriate to distinguish inverstors from other people. But that is your task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query [here](https://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT+distinct+%3Fperson+%3Flabel+%3FbirthPlace+%3FbirthDate+%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0A+%7B%0D%0A+++%3Fperson+rdf%3Atype+dbo%3APerson.%0D%0A+++%3Fperson+%3Fp+dbr%3AInvestor.%0D%0A+++%3Fperson+dbo%3Anationality+dbr%3AUnited_States.%0D%0A+++%3Fperson+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Flabel.+FILTER+%28lang%28%3Flabel%29+%3D+%27en%27%29%0D%0A+++OPTIONAL%7B%3Fperson+dbp%3AbirthPlace+%3FbirthPlace.%7D%0D%0A+++OPTIONAL%7B%3Fperson+dbo%3AbirthDate+%3FbirthDate+%7D%0D%0A+%7D%0D%0AUnion%0D%0A+%7B%0D%0A+++%3Fperson+rdf%3Atype+dbo%3APerson.%0D%0A+++%3Fperson+%3Fp+dbo%3AEntrepreneur.%0D%0A+++%3Fperson+dbo%3Anationality+dbr%3AUnited_States.%0D%0A+++%3Fperson+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Flabel.+FILTER+%28lang%28%3Flabel%29+%3D+%27en%27%29%0D%0A+++OPTIONAL%7B%3Fperson+dbp%3AbirthPlace+%3FbirthPlace.%7D+%0D%0A+++OPTIONAL%7B%3Fperson+dbo%3AbirthDate+%3FbirthDate+%7D%0D%0A+%7D%0D%0AUnion%0D%0A+%7B%0D%0A+++%3Fperson+rdf%3Atype+dbo%3APerson.%0D%0A+++%3Fperson+a+dbo%3ABusinessPerson.%0D%0A+++%3Fperson+dbo%3Anationality+dbr%3AUnited_States.%0D%0A+++%3Fperson+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Flabel.+FILTER+%28lang%28%3Flabel%29+%3D+%27en%27%29%0D%0A+++OPTIONAL%7B%3Fperson+dbp%3AbirthPlace+%3FbirthPlace.%7D+%0D%0A+++OPTIONAL%7B%3Fperson+dbo%3AbirthDate+%3FbirthDate+%7D%0D%0A+%7D%0D%0A%7D):

```
SELECT distinct ?person ?label ?birthPlace ?birthDate 
WHERE {
 {
   ?person rdf:type dbo:Person.
   ?person ?p dbr:Investor.
   ?person dbo:nationality dbr:United_States.
   ?person rdfs:label ?label. FILTER (lang(?label) = 'en')
   OPTIONAL{?person dbp:birthPlace ?birthPlace.} 
   OPTIONAL{?person dbo:birthDate ?birthDate }
 }
Union
 {
   ?person rdf:type dbo:Person.
   ?person ?p dbo:Entrepreneur.
   ?person dbo:nationality dbr:United_States.
   ?person rdfs:label ?label. FILTER (lang(?label) = 'en')
   OPTIONAL{?person dbp:birthPlace ?birthPlace.} 
   OPTIONAL{?person dbo:birthDate ?birthDate }
 }
Union
 {
   ?person rdf:type dbo:Person.
   ?person a dbo:BusinessPerson.
   ?person dbo:nationality dbr:United_States.
   ?person rdfs:label ?label. FILTER (lang(?label) = 'en')
   OPTIONAL{?person dbp:birthPlace ?birthPlace.} 
   OPTIONAL{?person dbo:birthDate ?birthDate }
 }
}
```

you can also try this equivalent query on wikidata SPARQL endpoint [here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fperson%20%3FpersonLabel%20%3Fdob%20%3FpobLabel%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5.%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP106%20wd%3AQ557880.%20%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP27%20wd%3AQ30.%20%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP569%20%3Fdob.%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP19%20%3Fpob.%20%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%20%0A%7D):

```
SELECT ?person ?personLabel ?dob ?pobLabel
WHERE 
{
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
  ?person wdt:P106 wd:Q557880. 
  ?person wdt:P27 wd:Q30. 
  OPTIONAL {?person wdt:P569 ?dob.}
  OPTIONAL {?person wdt:P19 ?pob. }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Arby Sidi, but I can't get it to work on either page:
https://live.dbpedia.org/sparql or https://dbpedia.org/snorql/

Comment: Now it works :) weren't as many as I hoped for, but thank you so much for the help.

Comment: I updated the query by adding Optional on dob and pob to get more results. I also added an equivalent query for the wikidata endpoint that you can try.

Comment: Thank you again so much! Do you think it's possible to extract over a thousand individuals from any of these pages, or are there other places I should be looking? The goal is to have something around 1500 individuals for statistical analysis.

Comment: You're welcome, Yes you can find more than 1500 in Diffbot.com